# Show a firebase-hosted webapp on different webpage

Tags: firebase, web, chatbot

I created a chatbot-gui using firebase and now I want to put this bot on a different website. The bot is hosted on a own webpage provided by firebase. The background behind the bot is blank and I want to display the bot "on-top" of a different website. I just want to add a script to the site which loads the Firebase Website and displays it on top of the website.

Sorry for the bad explanation but maybe somebody has already dealt with that topic.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to embed your site in an `iframe`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

If you only want the other website to include a JavaScript tag, then you can generate that `iframe` from within JavaScript:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "https://theurlofyoursite/"
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

There's much more to it of course, but this should allow you to get started.

I highly recommend doing some searches when you get stuck, as there's bound to be lots of documentation/tutorials/question out there already from developers who have done the same.

In addition, always remember that the web is open-source by definition. So if you know of a site that has what you want, check out the source for that site. While it may not always be readable, some of them may be very educational, and at the very least scanning the code should give you good terms to search for.